# Is it necessary to compile the inner class if changes made in an other inner class?

Tags: java, inner-classes

I have a Class Aouter, This Aouter class has 2 inner classes namely Binner,Cinner. My doubt is if Binner class had been changed so Cinner class also should be compiled and moved to server?

plz ask me if you have any doubt in my question.

Thank in advance.

Comment: This probably depends on the compiler and/or build system.  In general they aren't smart enough to tell which part of a source file is modified, only that it has been modified.  I would think that you would let the tools handle this and upload whatever they spit out.  `Cinner` is (probably) unchanged even though it has (very likely) been recompiled.  The compiler may be doing optimizations that effect `Cinner` if they have any interactions at all.  In general, I would think it's unsafe to assume that `Cinner` is unchanged.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `Cinner` does not depend on `Binner` in any way, it doesn't need to be recompiled. Otherwise I think it is better to recompile (although it may not be always necessary, it is still better to be on the safe side). But since in general inner classes are compiled together with their containing class, either all or none of them are recompiled in practice.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt you can compile them separately, but one inner class should not be affected by changes to another inner class. Since they generate different .class files why not use a tool like rsync for deploying your binaries (i.e. *moving to server*). That way only changes needs to be transferred..

Comment: rsync is automatic file transfer tool? but I can't use automated tool bze others can work in same server.

Comment: It is not *automatic*. Rather a smart copy/archive/synchronization tool, that moves only files around that have actually changed.

Answer (score 0):

If an inner class uses an outer class, to can make a difference.  This is because the compiler need to generate access methods when an inner class access a private member of an outer class.  This also means than if you change a field/method/constructor from non-private to private the inner class will change from a field access to a method call in the byte code.